# Django template won't display model object attributes on page

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am attempting to display the attributes of my model object in a Django template but the data will not appear in the page source.

In ***views.py***

```
    def view_func(request):
        ...
        data = ModelObj.objects.all()
        print(data)   #prints <QuerySet [ <ModelObj: ModelObj object (primary_key)>, ... ]> 
        return render(request, "templates/app/page.html", {'data': data})
```

In ***page.html***

```
... formatted html ...
<thead> ... </thead>
   <tbody>
   { % for i in data % }
        <tr>
            <td> {{ i.name }} </td>
            <td> {{ i.time }} </td>
            <td> {{ i.value }} </td>
        </tr>
        { % endfor % }
   </tbody>
```

When I view the ***page source*** after running the Django site:

```
... html ...
    <tbody>
        { % for i in data % }
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        { % endfor % }
    </tbody>
```

If I add `<td> {{data}} </td>` to the html page, I can see the `<QuerySet [ <ModelObj: ModelObj object (primary_key)>, ... ]>` display on the page, but Django will not display the model object attributes on the page. Any help with this error is appreciated, thank you.
EDIT: This is on Python 3.9 with Django version 3.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have **spaces between the percent sign % and curly brackets {}** in your jinja templating. That is **incorrect syntax**. The { and % should not contain spaces:

**Correct Syntax:**

```
{% for i in data %}
  <td> {{ i.name }} </td>
  <td> {{ i.time }} </td>
  <td> {{ i.value }} </td>
{% endfor %}
```

**Incorrect Syntax: (Spaces are wrong syntax)**

```
<!-- Incorrect Syntax -->
{ % for i in data % }
  <td> {{ i.name }} </td>
  <td> {{ i.time }} </td>
  <td> {{ i.value }} </td>
{ % endfor % }
```

The jinja templating should not be visible in page source, for example if the loop would run 3 times it would show the html tags thrice and not the jinja templating.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved the error! I had no idea that the spaces were incorrect syntax.